# php Removes duplicate values in foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach iterator, there are `500 group items` in it. How do I remove duplicate values in a foreach?

```
foreach ($data as $data) {
if(!empty($data['name'])){  //check if have $data['name']
$name = $data['name'];
$id = $data['id'];
$date = $data['date'];
$link = $data['link'];
if(strpos($link, '.ads.')){
continue; //remove all the link contains `.ads.`
}else{
// if `$link` is not repeat, echo the below data. how to use array_unique, remove all the values which repear in `$link` part? 
echo $name;
echo $id;
echo $date;
echo $link;
} 
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example duplicate value?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

```
foreach (array_unique($data) as $d) {
 // Do stuff with $d ...
}
```

Although you can technically call the array and its elements by the same name, it's bound to lead to programming errors and confusion afterwards.

Comment: +1. Here is a link to the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: @Asaph Beat you to it ;) Updated with a link.

Comment: add `array_unique` in `foreach (array_unique($data) as $d) {` there only one data return.

Comment: @yuli chika: inside the loop, use `$d`, not `$data`. Pay close attention to @phihag's advice: "Although you can technically call the array and its elements by the same name, it's bound to lead to programming errors and confusion afterwards."

Answer (score 3):

Look what you do:

```
foreach ($data as $data)
```

You are overwriting the contents of `$data`, then you access `$data` while you expect it still to be the original array. That's just wrong.

Take an additional variable name, pretty common is `$value`:

```
foreach ($data as $value)
```

Hope this helps even if it is not answering your question, but this can be part of your problem, so take care ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$fetch=$q->result();

$array_result= json_decode(json_encode($fetch), true);

$g=array();

    foreach($array_result as $p)
    {

      array_push($g,$p['email']);   

    }

$array=array_values(array_filter(array_unique($g)));
```

I was using this when i had o choose unique e-mail id's out of a number of similar emails which was coming via Ajax response...hope this helps u can ask queries if u do hv problem understanding anywhere..