# Remove multiple column duplicate value in Foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel-4.2

I use this code to display certain users per record in multiple property name. Though I wanted to display 1 name instead of multiple including their IDs.

```
@foreach( $records as $record )
  @if( $record->investment_type == null )
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $record->client_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $record->firstname }} {{ $record->lastname }}</td>
    <td>{{ $record->name }}</td>
    <td class="details-control"></td>
  </tr>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Here's the output of my current code.

[image]

While this is what i wanted to be looked like.

[image]

I tried, `array_unique` but the output gives me error

[image]

Source code came from this: [php Removes duplicate values in foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322312/php-removes-duplicate-values-in-foreach) and just followed what was solved the issue from the poster. But it don't work on my end.

Many thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:**

Here's the output of the `$records` from `var_dump`.

[image]

And this is the code inside controller.

```
$records = DB::table('assets')
                ->join('client', 'client.Id', '=', 'assets.client_id')
                ->join('property', 'property.Id', '=', 'assets.property_id')
                ->select('assets.client_id','client.firstname','client.lastname','property.name','assets.investment_type')
                ->orderBy('assets.client_id')
                ->get();
```

Comment: can you put the output of `echo "<pre>"; print_r($records)`.

Comment: there is one more way, Whyn't you add `distinct` or `groupby` in your query.

Comment: Where is your query? You can add Group By client_id in query.

Comment: why? its going to ruin sorting.

Comment: Yes OP will lose much details by that. All data can be added in 1 string in foreach for 1 user by combining all properties as he wants to remove duplicates.

Comment: then data will come like Id: 6, Full Name: John Doe and then all his properties data.

Comment: You can solve this with an if condition checking for the id

Comment: @hungrykoala yeah, im probably looking into that alternative solution. I liked Laravel, but it gives so much pain in my ass. Im just learning btw.

Comment: What you can do here is to store the `id` to a temp variable. and whenever that temp variable doesn't change you don't display `id` and `fullname` you only display it when the temp variable changes again

Answer (score 0):

Not much familiar in laravel syntax. You can just convert it if you want.
Anyway, to do this you need to check the previous value. I assume that this is sorted by name.

**First create a previous variable**

```
<?php $prev_value =  null;?>
```

**Here is the code where we check if it is the same in the previous value**

```
<?php if($prev_value == ($record->client_id)):?>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<?php else: ?>
<td>{{ $record->client_id }}</td>
<td>{{ $record->firstname }} {{ $record->lastname }}</td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**At the end of loop just add the current value in previous value variable**

```
<?php $prev_value = $record->client_id; ?>
```

**Whole Code**

```
<?php $prev_value =  null;?>
<?php foreach( $records as $record ): ?>
  <?php if( $record->investment_type == null ): ?>
  <tr>

    <?php if($prev_value == ($record->client_id)):?>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <?php else: ?>
    <td>{{ $record->client_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $record->firstname }} {{ $record->lastname }}</td>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <td>{{ $record->name }}</td>
    <td class="details-control"></td>

    <?php $prev_value = $record->client_id; ?>

  </tr>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: the whole idea is clear, but i lost John Doe property connections and left me 1 property connected to him.. i got 170 properties without connection to the names...

Comment: @iMarkDesigns what do you mean you lost property connections and left one property. Is my answer printing one property only?

Comment: in my example, I have 10 list of properties under John Doe, and when i use search, it display John Doe with 1 property list under him. This is  when I use your code, It does print all the properties but it display multiple property without ID and Names which i guess these are the users with multiple names..

Comment: @iMarkDesigns I updated my answer. Instead of using names to compare, just use client_id.

Comment: this is the output sir. Please add https to the url [cl.ly/1H423s0q0S3H]

Comment: @iMarkDesigns I updated my answer. please try it again.

Comment: still the same sir... anyway, thanks so much for your effort. I think I may need to check other alternatives and redo the controller coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use array_unique because you have an array of object.
Create an array of Id and an array of name,
In each loop you add the current id and the current name to theses arrays and before create the  you check if the current datas are in the array, if not you add them to the  if they already exist you create an empty .

Of course you have to check if Is in array from the second loop to display at minimums the first row.
Please note that this method is dirty because you do some logical operation in the view.
The best way is to do that on your model.